# Read / Write Office 365 document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365

I am new to use office 365, I want read office 365 document content using asp.net (C#), is there any api provide by office 365 for reading office 365 document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you men by "office 365 document"?
Office 365 can store any type of documents, from Office (Word, Excel) to binary files.

First, you need to access your file. If they are stored in SharePoint / Skydrive then you'll need both [ClientContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.web.aspx) and [SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx).
Then you'll need to add/remove/modify your file. If it's Office file then Matthew is correct, Open XML SDK is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Open XML SDK version 2.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for this.

There's [more information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850833.aspx).

You can use the SDK to open and parse ".docx" documents, which I think is what you need for Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to any document stored in SharePoint site then you can easily use it via SharePoint Online Client otherwise there are also some libraries in NuGET packages for Office 365 which enables support for Office 365 document reading or other stuff